# The type or namespace name 'ApiController' could not be found - Nuget is installed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget-package, asp.net-apicontroller

FrameWork : **.Net Framework 4.7.2.**

**Web api** project:
After pull code from git (worked and compiled on a different local machine), and trying to build,
getting:

```
**The type or namespace name 'ApiController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
```

regarding all apiController inherited class attributes and keywords :ApiController, HttpPost, FromBody, etc.),

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace POC_Book_Api.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] SomeCollection items)
```

System.Web Assembly is referenced in the project References.
Nuget **Microsoft.AspNet.Api** is installed and updated in the project.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Is also System.Web.Http in the Assembly?

Comment: @ChristianMüller - yes, it is - but it is gereyed - "Using directive is unnecessary"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to reinstall the package via Package Management Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
```

Please ensure you have the correct project selected and Package Source is nuget.org:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to reinstall (uninstall + install) the relevant packages. The problem was that while uninstalling it throught the Nuget package manager - it didn't actually uninstall it because other nuget packages was depending on it.
I was aware of it only after doing it using the Package manager console.
I unistalled all the dependencies - then the nuget itself and then install it again

Comment: oh. Since I had made a very simple setup (with only a test class), it worked for me. Good you find out... make sense that nuget doesn't deinstall it, when there depandencies...